# Manually defined Line in Line Chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2012

I have a report that's generating a chart showing student progress in a particular subject. There will be 15 data points in total, however at present only 2 have been completed. The line generated from these points of data works perfectly, however I want to include a second line which shows the path of expected progress. The values for the Y axis for this line simply need to be 4,8,12,16,20... down along the 15 points, however because only 2 data points have been collected thus far I can't figure out a way to make that line extend along the full graph. The reason for this is basically that the only way I can make it show at all is adding another Series where the data value is 4 * Fields!AP.Value, where AP is the number of the data point.

Is there a way to manually define values for a series, such that I can force a particular line to show on my chart?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was only a problem because I was forced to use a **Report Model**. I eventually resolved this by building my own DB and using API calls to the parent application to populate it with the same data and building my own queries!